# GSA API - Unable to get the Authentication Token

Tags: java, acl, google-search, google-search-appliance

I have been trying to get an Authentication Key for managing a Google Search Appliance and modify its Access Control Lists (ACLs).

This is my code:

```
    SocketAddress proxyAddress = new InetSocketAddress(PROXY_HOST,PROXY_PORT);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, proxyAddress);
    URL clientLoginUrl = new URL("https://my.server.com:8443/accounts/ClientLogin");
    HttpURLConnection clientLoginSecureConnection = 
        (HttpURLConnection)clientLoginUrl.openConnection(proxy);
    clientLoginSecureConnection.setDoInput(true);
    clientLoginSecureConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    clientLoginSecureConnection.setUseCaches(false);
    clientLoginSecureConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",          
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    content.append("Email=").append(
    URLEncoder.encode(Constants.GSA_AUTH_USER, "UTF-8"));
    content.append("&Passwd=").append(
    URLEncoder.encode(Constants.GSA_AUTH_PASSWORD, "UTF-8"));
    OutputStream outputStream = clientLoginSecureConnection.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(content.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    outputStream.close();
    // Retrieve the output
    int responseCode = clientLoginSecureConnection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Response code: " + responseCode);
    InputStream inputStream;
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        inputStream = clientLoginSecureConnection.getInputStream();
    } else {
        inputStream = clientLoginSecureConnection.getErrorStream();
    }
    String postOutput = toString(inputStream);
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(postOutput, "=\n ");
    String key = null;
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
        if (tokenizer.nextToken().equalsIgnoreCase("Auth")) {
            if (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                key = tokenizer.nextToken();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    if (key == null) {
    System.out.println("Error response from server:\n" + postOutput);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Key found: " + key);
}
```

I have followed the instructions [here](http://code.google.com/intl/es-419/apis/searchappliance/documentation/60/gdata/acapi_policy_acls.html#pPolicyACLAPIDevGuideProtocol) but I always get this exception:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection
>   during handshake  at
>       com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:808)
>         at
>       com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1120)
>         at
>       com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1147)
>         at
>       com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1131)
>         at
>       sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
>         at
>       sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
>         at
>       sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:904)
>         at
>       sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
>         at
>       com.mycompany.gslisting.GetKeysTestCase.testGetAccessControlListKeys(GetKeysTestCase.java:90)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>         at
>       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>       junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)   at
>       junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)   at
>       junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)     at
>       junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)  at
>       junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)   at
>       junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)   at
>       junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)     at
>       junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)     at
>       org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
>         at
>       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>         at
>       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>         at
>       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>         at
>       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>         at
>       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>         at
>       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>       Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly   at
>       com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:333)
>         at
>       com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:789)
>         ... 27 more

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

I just followed the instructions in [this site](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=210).
What I did was downloading the site certificate (.cer) using a browser (Chrome) and import it to the default keystore by running:

```
#keytool -import -alias GSAAPI -file ./GSA.cer
```